# What is the best way to work with nested JSON structures in Golang?

Tags: json, go

Id like to work with JSON in Golang, in particular the elastic search JSON protocol.

The JSON is deeply nested (this is a simple query):

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
                "and": [
                    {
                        "range" : {
                            "b" : { 
                                "from" : 4, 
                                "to" : "8"
                            }
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "a": "john"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This structure maps easily to a native data structure in Ruby.

But with Golang, it seems you have to define the exact structure with structs (perhaps generate them programmatically from the JSON source).

Even so, things like arrays of different "types" of objects in JS requires work arounds and custom code. For example the "and" key in the example JSON. (http://mattyjwilliams.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/using-go-to-unmarshal-json-lists-with.html).

Is there a better way to work with JSON in Golang?

Comment: I still recommend making the actual structs. Just as in any other language you get over the arrays of different types with polymorphism. The required structs in Go are the same as the structures I would use in any other language. Other models may work fine in some situations but overall are just a short cut, they aren't actually better at anything other than saving the developer a few minutes up front.

Comment: Not answering because someone is likely to have a better solution, but you can always just work with nested `map[string]interface{}` and `[]interface{}`s.

Comment: Also, if you want to use something like the maps structure in Ruby (again, I think that's just bad practice and would only ever use it in tools that I write for my own use) then you're looking for `map[string]interface{}` but all the silly casts/type asserts required to make use of your data will quickly overrun the lines saved by not defining the structs.

Answer (score 5):

If you choose to go the struct route, consider this example:

```
{"data": {"children": [
  {"data": {
    "title": "The Go homepage",
    "url": "http://golang.org/"
  }},
  ...
]}}

// -----------

type Item struct {
    Title string
    URL   string
}

type Response struct {
    Data struct {
        Children []struct {
            Data Item
        }
    }
}
```

Source: http://talks.golang.org/2012/10things.slide#4

Answer (score 4):

One of the options is to use gabs library: https://github.com/Jeffail/gabs

It's useful for parsing and generating of the complex json structures.

This is the example of the nested json generation from the README:

```
jsonObj := gabs.New()
// or gabs.Consume(jsonObject) to work on an existing map[string]interface{}

jsonObj.Set(10, "outter", "inner", "value")
jsonObj.SetP(20, "outter.inner.value2")
jsonObj.Set(30, "outter", "inner2", "value3")
```

Will print:

```
{"outter":{"inner":{"value":10,"value2":20},"inner2":{"value3":30}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

For native golang, use `map[string]interface{}` or define a struct.
For an other way to access json object easily, may be [JsonPath](https://github.com/yasuyuky/jsonpath) or [Jason](https://github.com/antonholmquist/jason)

Answer (score 0):

Based on this article, https://medium.com/@xcoulon/nested-structs-in-golang-2c750403a007, you should define json tags for each field, then you are able to use nested struct
The example is below, you can paste it to go playground and test it.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)
type Config struct {
    Server struct {
        Host string `json:"host"`
        Port string `json:"port"`
        } `json:"server"`
    Postgres struct {
        Host     string `json:"host"`
        User     string `json:"user"`
        Password string `json:"password"`
        DB       string `json:"db"`
    } `json:"database"`
}

func main() {
    jsonConfig := []byte(`{
        "server":{
            "host":"localhost",
            "port":"8080"},
        "database":{
            "host":"localhost",
            "user":"db_user",
            "password":"supersecret",
            "db":"my_db"}}`)
    var config Config
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonConfig, &config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Config: %+v\n", config)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `struct` is the best option, if you are willing to do it. One item that can help, is if you are only using a struct once, you can just define it at the same time you are declaring it, rather than with a `type` keyword. Another item, is you only need to define fields that you actually use, others you can omit. Finally, as long as you can case insensitively match the source field names, then you don't need to worry about `struct` tags:

```
package main
import "encoding/json"

const s = `
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {"match_all": {}},
         "filter": {
            "and": [
               {"range" : {"b" : {"from": 4, "to": "8"}}},
               {"term": {"a": "john"}}
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
`

func main() {
   var m struct {
      Query struct {
         Filtered struct {
            Filter struct { And []struct { Term struct { A string } } }
         }
      }
   }
   json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &m)
   println(m.Query.Filtered.Filter.And[1].Term.A == "john")
}
```